# /etc/inittab respawn already running process, Debian9

Tags: init-script, init, sysvinit

I added an antry in `/etc/inittab` to respawn a binary. The entry is like:

```
id:2:respawn:/path-to-my-bin
```

I then execute `init q` and the process is started by `inittab`. If I kill the process, it's respawned.

### The problem

The strange behaviour happens when I do the following:

1. manually run `/path-to-my-binary`
2. add the entry above in `/etc/inittab`
3. run `init q`

Result: the process is respawned even though it was already running.

Moreover, if the binary was set to be run on startup with `init.d`, at runlevel 2, the `inittab` respawns it immediately at boot.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is: Don't do it this way.

If you want to have your process handled according to the configuration in `/etc/inittab` you must not start it manually or somewhere else.

`init` does not check existing processes if there is a match bewtween the process' command and an entry in `inittab`. It only monitors its children, i.e. processes started by `init` itself.
When you run `init q`, the `init` process knows that it has not (yet) started a process for your line `id:2:respawn:/path-to-my-bin` and starts it.

---

Unfortunately I don't know where this is explicitly specified.
For me it is clear that it must be this way for several reasons:

1. `init` will get a signal when a child process terminates, so it can get the status of the process, check the specification from `inittab` and restart the process if necessary. This is event based. For unrelated processes this would not be possible, so `init` would have to check all processes. This probably would be polling.
2. `init` doesn't know what is intended with a separate process executing the same command as one of the `inittab` lines. It may or may not be desired behavior to run a second instance of the process.
3. What would you expect `init` to do if you start the program manually after `init` has already started an instance according to `inittab`? What if the process started by `inittab` would terminate later? Or if the other process terminated later?

As there are many open questions it is natural for `init` to handle its child processes only and to ignore any unrelated process.

Comment: Thank you. Where can I find specific documentation about this behavior? It's not stated in the inittab man page.

Comment: Ok, your points are very reasonable.